# Non-existent class: Template - Upgrade to Code Igniter 3.0.0

Tags: php, codeigniter, logging, error-handling, upgrade

I am upgrading **CodeIgniter** from **2.2.0** to **3.0.0**

it said

> 404 Page Not Found Oops, the page you're looking for was not found or
>   unavailable. An Error Was Encountered
>
> Non-existent class: Template

```
ERROR - 2015-03-31 23:02:10 --> Non-existent class: Template
ERROR - 2015-03-31 23:02:31 --> Non-existent class: Template
```

i checked on the loader.php there's no template.php

---

---

> An Error Was Encountered
>
> Cannot write to the 'title' region. The region is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the class name to Template instead of CI_Template. Also make sure to change the constructor of the class.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with a library, `system/libraries/className.php` and solved it by changing it to `application/libraries`. I guess you have to do the same.

Comment: It doesn't really answer the question. But, the problem `Non-existent class` in the question usually occured when loading libraries from `system/libraries` (CI3.x)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to change the class name from `CI_Template` to `Template` and also change the constructor from `CI_Template` to `Template`.

The path of "Template" class is

> root/application/libraries/Template.php

Secondly, go to

> root/application/config/template.php

and add you own regions. For example:

```
$template['default']['template'] = 'template';
$template['default']['regions'] = array(
   'header',
   'title',
   'content',
   'footer',
);
$template['default']['parser'] = 'parser';
$template['default']['parser_method'] = 'parse';
$template['default']['parse_template'] = FALSE;
```

This has worked for me.